# Regex to match anything except HTML tags when code is encoded using &lt; and &gt;

Tags: regex, ruby, html-parsing, ruby-1.9.3

I am trying to use regex to match any text except for HTML tags. I have found this solution for "normal" HTML code:

```
<[^>]*>(*SKIP)(*F)|[^<]+
```

However, my code is encoded using `&lt;` and `&gt;` instead of `<` and `>`, and I have not been able to modify the regex above for it to work.

As an example, given the text:

`Hi &lt;p class=\"hello\"&gt;\r\nthere, how are you\r\n&lt;/p&gt;`

I need to match "hi" and "there, how are you". Note that I need to match text that is not between tags as well, "hi", in this example.

UPDATE: since I am using ruby's gsub, it looks like I cannot even use *SKIP and *F

UPDATE 2:  I was trying not to get into much detail but seems to be important:
I actually need to replace all the spaces from a text, but not those spaces that are part of a tag, be it a `&lt; ... &gt;` tag or a `<...>` tag.

Comment: Can you run  regex split with `(?s)&lt;.*?&gt;`?

Comment: It might be like `&lt;(?:(?!&gt;)[\s\S])*&gt;(*SKIP)(*F)|(?:(?!&lt;)[\s\S])+` https://regex101.com/r/TjrIOo/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that i sa good idea, I could use split but I need to reconstruct the text, I am using ruby's gsub and by using split I'd lose the tags' content

Comment: @Thefourthbird  oh that works perfectly! but I just tried and looks like ruby (1.9.3) does not support *SKIP and *FAIL...  I am gonna update the question

Comment: Ok, 1) you are using Ruby, 2) you have `text = "Hi &lt;p class=\"hello\"&gt;\r\nthere, how are you\r\n&lt;/p&gt;"`, 3) what do you need to get?

Comment: I need to substitute all spaces for some other characters but only for the text that is not part of the tags (neither <> tags or &lt; &gt; tags). I did not go into that much detail because it is too specific. I was trying to first match it to get the texts and afterwards (inside gsub loop) look for spaces in each of these texts.

Comment: That is all very important. Try `text.gsub(/(&lt;.*?&gt;|<[^>]*>)|[[:blank:]]/m) { $1 || '_' }`. I suggest `[[:blank:]]` instead of `\s` since I assume you do not want to replace line breaks.

Comment: That is perfect!!! Could it be so it works for both &lt; &gt; and < > tags? I am going to explain the question in more detail in the description and you can post this as an answer so I can select it as the solution. What a headache you just saved me, thank you so much, I'll be "buymeacoffee"-ing you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```rb
text = text.gsub(/(&lt;.*?&gt;|<[^>]*>)|[[:blank:]]/m) { $1 || '_' }
```

I suggest `[[:blank:]]` instead of `\s` since I assume you do not want to replace line breaks. See the [Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/7X2ohK).

The regex above matches

- `(&lt;.*?&gt;|<[^>]*>)` - either `&lt;`, any zero or more chars as few as possible, and `&gt;` or `<`, then zero or more chars other than `>` and then a `>`
- `|` - or
- `[[:blank:]]` - any single horizontal whitespace (you may also use `[\p{Zs}\t]` to match any Unicode horizontal whitespace).

The `{ $1 || '_' }` block in the replacement means that when Group 1 matches, the Group 1 value is returned as is, else, `_` is returned as a replacement of a horizontal whitespace.